# Android Studio gradle experimental test (JUNit)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, junit4

I'm trying to test my class with InstrumentationTestCase. I've been checking the examples but I guess I'm missing something because "Test Artifact" dropdown is disabled and cannot be changed to JUNit.

I declared the libraries in gradle

```
// Test Compile
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
testCompile 'org.reflections:reflections:0.9.9'
```

declared app id,

```
defaultConfig {
    testApplicationId "myproject.android.test"
  }
```

and getting the latest gradle version

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
    }
```

also created a build configuration for my test package. But when I run the test it gives me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/textui/ResultPrinter
```

probably because Test Artifact is "Android Instrumentation Tests" and the build configuration is JUNit configuration. Test Artifact dropdown is disabled so I cannot change it to JUNit. Is there something that I'm missing?

Edit:
my package tree is like this,

```
myproject
 - app
   - main
    - java
      -myproject
       -android
        -mypackage
         -myclass.java
   -test
    -java
     -myproject
      -android
       -mypackage
        -test
         -myclasstest.java
```

and in Android Studio preferences, under Gradle->Experimental, "Enable Unit Testing support" is checked.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do a few steps to activate JVM unit tests in Android Studio. Follow this steps: https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/unit-testing-support

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that I also activated Unit test from gradle options. This was the documentation that I've been following, still I cannot select JUnit from the test artifact list.

Comment: Also I realized that whenever I switch back to build variants segment, a popup shows up and say that I need 1.0.0+ grade or newer, and I've been getting it with .+ .

Comment: Did you activate the Unit Testing support in the gradle settings at the Android Studio settings? Are your unit tests code at the src/test folder?

Comment: yup, you need gradle 1.1 at least. Update in your build gradle project to         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'

Comment: see my edited answer please, I added somethings that I forgot to mention. I'm starting to think it's because of my gradle version, which I'm getting with classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+' as I mentioned before, that should be the last version right?

Comment: Yes, replace with my previous suggestion 1.1.3

Comment: Yea It is working now. Weird.. I even tried with 1.+ but guess + indicator does not work the way I think. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @BarışcanKayaoğlu How did you activate Unit test from gradle options?? I do not see this feature in Android Studio.

Comment: Did you update your AS to 1.1.0? If thats the case, under preferences, expand gradle at the left menu and select experimental. There will be a checkbox "Enable Unit Testing support". When you do, under build variants, Unit Test in Test Artifact dropdown will be available. If not, try to solve what @IgorGanapolsky said.

Comment: @BarışcanKayaoğlu I am on Android Studio 1.2 RC 3.